# How to change value of input when loading file from server using FilePond?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, filepond

Hi guy I'm using Filepond to upload and load file.
When I load file already existed on server, filepond rendered the input with value:
[Input value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glbps.png)

But I expect the value of the input is just file name of my file.

How can I change the input value when loading file from server?

Answer (score 0):

When you up load a file to the server? You only ever get the file name. For reasons of security no path name, no drive name, and nothing about the client computer is included in the file name.
You also can't set nor change nor mess with the filename provided. This is done for reasons of security. Can't have you come to my site and while you look at a cute cat pictures I then start running around on your computer looking for files called banking or my passwords.

However, interesting enough when you provide a file for download to user's computer, your full file name and path is sent to the browser. You could guess what location, but then again it might not even a windows computer your downloading the file to.

So you need to strip out the path name when sending the file to client side.

Path.getfilename(strFile) should work.
It's not clear how you download files (readbinary, or a link).

So automatic stripping of path name doesn't occur when you send a file to client. But if you strip out path part, then it will default to the downloads folder.